# Refactoring singleton classes that share similar function into a Base class - problems with generics

Tags: java, android

I am trying to refactor some of my request manager classes that share duplicate code:

```
public class PayoutChargesManager<T> extends BaseManager<T>{
    private static PayoutChargesManager instance = null;

    public static synchronized PayoutChargesManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new PayoutChargesManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

public class PayoutChargesInDayManager<T> extends BaseManager<T> {
    private static PayoutChargesInDayManager instance = null;

    public static synchronized PayoutChargesInDayManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new PayoutChargesInDayManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

public class OrdersHistoryManager<T> extends BaseManager<T> {
    private static OrdersHistoryManager instance = null;

    public static synchronized OrdersHistoryManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new OrdersHistoryManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I am trying to only have one copy of `getInstance()` in my BaseManager, and have PayoutChargesManager, PayoutChargesInDayManager and OrdersHistoryManager reuse it, but I am having some trouble implementing it.

```
public class BaseManager<T> implements OnApiCallListener {
    private static BaseManager<T> instance = null;

    public static synchronized BaseManager<T> getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) {
          instance = new BaseManager()<T>;
      }
      return instance;
  }
}
```

How do I implement this correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to refactor here? Is your objective to have a single `getInstance` method in the `BaseManager` that should be reused by all its subclasses and support `generics`?

Comment: @mystarrocks Yeah, my goal is to have a single `getInstance` in BaseManager that the other Managers can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot create an instance of `BaseManager<T>` using `new BaseManager<T>()` because T is not an actual type. There needs to be some actual type between the angle brackets. The alternative is to instantiate the raw type `BaseManager` using `new BaseManager()`, but that defeats the purpose of your generics and can lead to some awful bugs.
2. Static methods cannot be overridden by subclasses. They can only be hidden if the subclass declares a static method with the same name.

I would make BaseManager abstract and remove `getInstance()` from it. You can still have your subclasses inherit common behavior from it, but having a `getInstance()` method in it is at best confusing and at worst incorrect.

Comment: Okay, sounds fair enough. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overcomplicating it. Firstly, the type parameter `T` will not be available in the context of a `static` method, so you can never write a common `static` `getInstance()` method in your base class.

Besides, you are trying to maintain a single instance of `BaseManager` (i.e its subtype) - what will happen to other subtypes when of those subtypes occupies the `instance` reference?

You are better off making the `getInstance` method `abstract` (and so non-static) and let the subtypes provide their own implementation (you will lose the singletonness, though). Or write a factory class called `Managers` that would always get its clients singleton instances of the managers, if you intend to maintain the singletonness.

Comment: Making `getInstance()` non-static means not using the Singleton pattern, as you would then need an instance of the singleton to call `getInstance()`.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have paid attention. Editing my post.